# Is there a difference between Lenience and Leniency? Google defines them the same way but is one the modern version and the other the older one?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary, nuance

The Google definition for both words is: he fact or quality of being more merciful or tolerant than expected; clemency.

Which one is used most nowadays?
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to ELU, marcel. Please show some evidence of research (at least a couple of dictionary definitions). While these probably won't fully answer your question, they will show others which dictionaries _don't_ give detailed-enough definitions.

Comment: LENIENCE: the fact or quality of being more merciful or tolerant than expected; clemency.

LENIENCY: the fact or quality of being more merciful or tolerant than expected; clemency.

Definitions provided by Google.

Comment: Please edit the _question_ to show your research and also source it.

Comment: Okay, so your definitions show that Googles

Answer (score -1):

Which one is used more nowadays?

[image]

[ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/interactive_chart?content=leniency%2Clenience&year_start=1900&year_end=2010&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cleniency%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clenience%3B%2Cc0)

Note: In the future, do this kind of look-up yourself before asking here.

Comment: Why, for once, when an ngram is useful, is it being downvoted?? I just don't get it.